# VS can't find NuGet package

Tags: visual-studio, npm, nuget

After referring to:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pixplorer-api
Where to use the pixplorer api it requires you to download the pixplorer-api package. It displays here that the package has 211 downloads.
However, after searching for 'pixplorer-api' the Nuget Package manager in Visual Studio no results are shown. 
Any tips would be appreciated about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package you're browsing is an NPM package for Node. The fact that there is a node package doesn't mean that there is an equivalent NuGet package. They're two different things, unfortunately.

[Nuget.org says there is no such package](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=pixplorer-api):
[image]

Which means that Visual Studio will show you the same message.

If you want to install NPM packages into a Visual Studio project you'll need to install the task runner for Visual Studio and setup a `package.json`:

- [NPM Script taskrunner support](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8f2f2cbc-4da5-43ba-9de2-c9d08ade4941)
- [Task runner explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708) (for 2013, it's integrated into 2015)

See also: [Introducing Gulp, Grunt, Bower and NPM support for Visual Studio](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx).